# Boost UpgradeLockable Concept

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Why Boost UpgradeLockable Concept (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable) have unlock_and_lock_* and unlock_upgrade_and_lock_* but don't have unlock_shared_and_lock_*? It have try_unlock_shared_and_lock_* but only when BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_SHARED_MUTEX_UPWARDS_CONVERSIONS is available and I don't want to "try". There's some restriction about doing such operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire purpose of an upgradeable lock is that you can atomically upgrade it to an exclusive lock. If you could do that with a shared lock, what purpose would upgradeable locks serve?

If you had an `unlock_shared_and_lock`, what would happen if two threads called it at the same time? Under what circumstances would it be safe to call?

If you might need to atomically upgrade a lock, you need to acquire an upgradeable lock. That's their entire purpose.

Comment: `If you had an unlock_shared_and_lock, what would happen if two threads called it at the same time?`
As I understand should happen same thing that happening when I'm locking exclusive ownership on two threads at same time. Who first grab it will have it. Others threads should be blocked.
`If you might need to atomically upgrade a lock, you need to acquire an upgradeable lock`
It's fine for me, but why there's no unlock_shared_and_lock_upgrade? There's try version, but I don't want to try.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The thread that calls first *can't* grab it because the other thread holds a shared lock and you can't get an exclusive lock while another thread holds a shared lock. Both threads are saying "I won't release my lock until I get a lock I can only lock after the other thread releases its lock".